# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'. LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I'm really stuck with my libgdx's project setup on Android Studio.

I create a project with libgdx, imported through gradle, made a setup for desktop, but when I run it, i got this error. Please help me figure it out.

[image]

I'm beginner, so any information about this error would be very useful to me. Thanks n
Respect in advance.

UPDATE*******
[image]

Comment: it seem you have a compile error that occurred during the build , i think you are missing brakets '{' as indicated in your log, could you show us your code

Comment: @minos23 brakets should not be the case, double checked it. Added a photo of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a space in the name of your class.

Try this:

```
public class GunRun extends ApplicationAdapter {
    ...
}
```

Please see the [Java naming Standard](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html).